# How to make an onclick function change the src for two images

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

I'm supposed to add script to an HTML file so that when I click the first star in the star rating system, it will change the src to 'star-on.png' as opposed to 'star-off.png'. That, I can do. But I can't figure out how to make it so that if the user clicks the second star, it will change the src for both the first and the second star to 'star-on.png'.

Here's the code that my teacher provided:

```
<!-- 1. PUT YOUR NAME IN THIS COMMENT -->
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- 2. DO NOT EDIT THE CSS -->
        <style type="text/css">
            body {
                margin: 0;
            }
            div {
                width: 520px;
                display: block;
                margin-left: auto;
                margin-right: auto;
            }

            img {
                width: 100px;
            }
        </style>
        <!-- 2.5 YOU MAY ALTER THE STYLING OF THE BUTTON IF YOU WISH. --> 
        <style type="text/css">
            button {
                width: 200px;
                display: block;
                margin-left: auto;
                margin-right: auto;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <!-- 3. DO NOT ALTER THE HTML EXCEPT TO ADD ONCLICK, ONLOAD, AND SIMILAR ATTRIBUTES -->
    <!-- AS NEEDED -->
    <body>
        <div>
            <img src="star-off.png"  id="one" class="2">
            <img src="star-off.png" id="two" class="2">
            <img src="star-off.png" id="three">
            <img src="star-off.png" id="four">
            <img src="star-off.png" id="five">
        </div>
        <button id="reset" onclick="document.getElementById('one').src='star-off.png'">Reset</button>
        <!-- 4. YOU MAY PUT YOUR SCRIPTING HERE -->

        <script>
            document.getElementById('one').onclick = function () {
            document.getElementById('one').src="star-on.png";
            }
            document.getElementById('two').onclick = function () {
            document.getElementById('two').src="star-on.png";
            }
            document.getElementById('three').onclick = function () {
            document.getElementById('three').src="star-on.png";
            }
            document.getElementById('four').onclick = function () {
            document.getElementById('four').src="star-on.png";
            }
            document.getElementById('five').onclick = function () {
            document.getElementById('five').src="star-on.png";
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Except for the things inside the script tag and the onclick inside of the button, it's all my teacher's code.

This is what it looks like:

[image: What it looks like]

Comment: Please post your code as code, not as a screenshot. To do this, copy-paste your code and then select it and press CTRL+K to format it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you've really got most of what you're trying to do in your script already. Look at each of these lines:

```js
document.getElementById('one').onclick = function () {
    document.getElementById('one').src="star-on.png";
}
document.getElementById('two').onclick = function () {
    document.getElementById('two').src="star-on.png";
}
document.getElementById('three').onclick = function () {
    document.getElementById('three').src="star-on.png";
}
document.getElementById('four').onclick = function () {
    document.getElementById('four').src="star-on.png";
}
document.getElementById('five').onclick = function () {
    document.getElementById('five').src="star-on.png";
}
```

Essentially, each one is saying select the element by its Id attribute, identified in the preceding group by the 'id=""' in this part:

```
<img src="star-off.png"  id="one" class="2">
<img src="star-off.png" id="two" class="2">
<img src="star-off.png" id="three">
<img src="star-off.png" id="four">
<img src="star-off.png" id="five">
```

and then attach an onclick event to it. When that onclick event fires, do the function that you've defined to the right of each of the equal signs following the event specification.

Inside each of your functions, it is simply going to identify the element on the DOM that matches the element id you're providing (just as you already did to assign the event handler in the previous section) and you're going to change the value for its 'src' attribute to the string you're defining on the right side of the equals.

Take the second one, per your request. Here's the HTML you're referencing (for both the first and second stars):

```
<img src="star-off.png"  id="one" class="2">
<img src="star-off.png" id="two" class="2">
```

And here is the event handler you've already got in place for the second one:

```
document.getElementById('two').onclick = function () {
    document.getElementById('two').src="star-on.png";
}
```

Right now if you click on that second star, you're only changing the src attribute of the element with an ID of 'two' to the 'star-on.png' image. So, if you want to also change the element of the star before it, it's got an ID of 'one', so you'll need to add this line within the event handler.

```
document.getElementById('one').src = "star-on.png";
```

Sure, there are more efficient ways to do this, but undoubtedly you'll learn about them as your course progresses. Here's what your event handler will look like with this update:

```
document.getElementById('two').onclick = function () {
    document.getElementById('two').src="star-on.png";
    document.getElementById('one').src = "star-on.png";
}
```

Comment: Oh thank you. I knew it was going to be something easy like that. Thank you for helping me and for explaining it so thoroughly. You just saved my grade!